# interface hierarchy instance C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

InterfaceA contains GetName method

InterfaceB implements Interface A and contains GetStatus Method

```
foreach(InterfaceA item in tempList.getList()){
if(item is Interface B)
rootNode = new TreeNode(item.GetName);
rootNode.Tag = item
childNode = new TreeNode(item.GetStatus) <--**is this possible>? or is there any solution on getting instance with child interface from the parent?**
childNode.Tag = item
}
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Please spend some time making it more clear and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A easier solution is to use `as` instead of `is`. What `as` will do is return the interface if it can be cast or null if it can not.

```
foreach(InterfaceA item in tempList.getList())
{
    rootNode = new TreeNode(item.GetName());
    rootNode.Tag = item

    InterfaceB itemB = item as InterfaceB;
    if(itemB != null)
    {
        childNode = new TreeNode(itemB.GetStatus())
        childNode.Tag = itemB
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use explicit cast when access methods of child class/interface from a reference of parent class/interface. And of course you have to be sure the cast is legit, what is controlled by `if(item is Interface B)` in your code.

```
childNode = new TreeNode(((InterfaceB)item).GetStatus())
```

Comment: You need a extra set of parenthesis to make the cast happens before the `.` to call the function: `TreeNode(((InterfaceB)item).GetStatus())`

Comment: Fixed for the great justice )